# How can I place my bed on glass blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm a little confused by why I can't place a bed on a floor of glass in 1.7.2.  I can place other objects, such as furnaces and crafting tables, without difficulty.  However, my bed refuses to be placed.  How can I get around this and why is it happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed):

> Like certain other blocks, beds can not be placed on snow, ice, glowstone, **glass**, carpet or leaves. If you remove the blocks underneath the bed, the bed will not be removed, but will remain floating. **To put a bed on glass** you must use this trick to make the bed float, and after that place the glass underneath.

(Emphasis mine)

For an alternative explanation, see [this video](https://i.3v.fi/1404570348.mp4).

Comment: Whilst this works for sleeping on, later visitors might want to know that it will not function as a spawn point (giving the obstruction error) if placed in the above way.